# Facebook like event handling not working if user is not logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook page. I want to know if a person has clicked on like button or not and do something in `subscribe.event 'create-edge'` callback.
This works fine if a person is already logged into Facebook. The `'create-edge'` event is getting fired. However, if a person is not logged in, this event is not getting fired.

I don't have any `appId`, so I'm sending it nothing.

Code for your reference:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Facebook Like Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '', // App ID
  channelURL : '', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : false, // enable OAuth 2.0
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert("say something");
    //my code
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});   
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
</script>
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/My_Page" send="false" layout="button_count"     width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

And also i am getting this error:

> FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

Seems like I am getting it because I don't have any `appId` to send in `FB.init`.
What is the cause of this?

Comment: are you even calling `FB.getLoginStatus()` in your code?

Comment: no i am not calling it but still i am getting this error.

Comment: I would try, instead of setting appId and channelURL to '', just omit them.  If that doesn't work, why don't you just create an 'app', so you actually have values to use there?

Comment: You tried both my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the user has already liked your page, and is not logged in. To fix this, I had to put FB.init() in a loop.. like this:

```
setInterval(function()
        {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'app_id'
                channelUrl : 'channel_url'
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
            });

        }, 5000);
```